# How to solve Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation error

Tags: logging, log4j, websphere, java.util.logging

Hi I just want to ask for your help to solve below error I’m experiencing during startup of WAS 9
SystemErr: R Error StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console
This happened after we upgrade our application from java 5 to java 8 and WAS 6.1 to WAS 9. I don’t know how to solve the issue, we are not even using log4j2, we are only using log4j (log4j-1.2.14.jar) Really need your help guys. Let me know the easiest way to solve this. In the code, we’re only using log4j.properties and commons-logging.properties.

Comment: Where did you package your logging properties and log4j jars, and is it possible to share a bit more of the exception stack (to get some context for where this is happening)?

Comment: properties is under App\AppWeb\JavaSource and jar is under WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: It is only showing this error in the logs:SystemErr: R Error StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console

Comment: Did you try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48566276/3758602)