# Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation while trying to start Sonar Qube local instance

Tags: java, logging, plugins, sonarqube, log4j2

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console... while trying to start Sonar Qube local instance.

Comment: It's may be a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881821/error-statuslogger-log4j2-could-not-find-a-logging-implementation

Comment: I haven't used log4j2 anywhere in my code and also I'm facing this problem when I'm trying to start Sonar Qube local instance on my machine. It doesn't seems to be duplicate one

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sonar 7.9.3 version and faced similar issue. Changing the JDK version from 1.8 to jdk-11.0.9 Fixed the issue